# Why do iOS apps recently change authentication method?

Tags: ios, authentication, oauth, twitter-oauth, facebook-oauth

Recently I just notice how Path, Pinterest, and the like change the way they authenticate their users. Currently it seems that they require us to create an account associated with Facebook or Twitter. I could not understand the reason behind this. Is there any security concern for them to make this move?

Why is simple authentication with Facebook and Twitter not enough?

Comment: That gives them the opportunity to have the user link to multiple accounts, and switch them later. They won't depend on Facebook or Twitter forever.

Comment: I see. @Thilo, please change your comment to an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is about giving the site more control over their future and the relationship to their users.

If they have their own account system, but allow the users to link it to Facebook or Twitter, that link can later be changed if the relationship with those providers turns sour.

Answer (score 1):

The big reason is that they don't have to take any risk with handling passwords, etc. which can get hacked. They are offloading the security of user accounts to bigger partners, so they don't have to worry about it.